# htaccess 301 redirection when parameter "p" is present in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My wordpress website been hacked and google keeps crawling Urls with a certain parameter **leis**,
My question is, how to radirect to 404 any url containing **leis** parameter
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to radirect to 404 any url containing **leis** parameter?

You can use the following Rule for this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#If  "leis" is present in the query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?leis [NC]
#forword the request to 404
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Infortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @Yazuk what url are you going to?

Comment: **ANYTHING-HERE**/?leis=%5B165%2F60R14%5DHANKOOK-%2F-WINTER-icept-IZ-W606-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9-%5B2%2F-%5D%5BBEST-%2F-Razee-XS-14%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81-(BKP)%5D-pq449794p